Ncat: Connection Refused when connecting on Linux server
I created a java application and ran it with docker inside a linux server XX.XX.XX.XX. That application should listen behind port 105 of that server. In fact, by executing the "netstat -an | grep 105" instruction I obtain the following result:
# netstat -an | grep 105
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:105             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::105                  :::*                    LISTEN  

However, when testing that port (both within the server itself and from my PC) I get the error "Connection refused.":
# nc -v XX.XX.XX.XX 105
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.

Finally, trying to execute the same instruction inside the server but using localhost everything seems to work:
# nc -v localhost 105
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ::1:105.

What could be the problem? What might I need to check?

Can you please share how you ran your Docker container? What parameters you passed in docker run command? If you used docker compose file, please share it.
